# Cmake/matlab: FIND_PROGRAM does not find mex and mexext

Tags: matlab, cmake, mex

I'm absolutely new to compiling stuff and am trying to cmake a CMakeList.txt with  following (reduced) content (comments are my interpretation of what the code does):

```
FIND_PROGRAM(MEX_CMD mex)  # find programm mex and save in variable MEX_CMD
FIND_PROGRAM(MEXEXT_CMD mexext) # same for mexext

IF(MEX_CMD AND MEXEXT_CMD) # returns true if both variables exist, currently always returns false
    ...
ELSE()
MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR
    "Cannot find MATLAB or Octave instalation. Make sure that the 'bin' directory from the MATLAB instalation is in PATH"
)
```

Since the if statement always returns FALSE and I get the error message, I suppose it doesn't find mex or/and mexext. I tried to add the directory which contains both files to the path without any effect:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin)
```

Now i'm out of ideas. Where could the problem be? On a side note, in bash `which -a mexext` returns nothing. I'm using ubuntu 16.10, cmake 3.5.2.

Comment: Are you sure 'bin' is in path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `find_program` [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_program.html) you have several possibilities to "hint" CMake about location of the program.

**Via modification** of `CMakeLists.txt` (if you are the author of the script):

- *PATHS* or *HINTS* option for find_program:

  ```
  find_program(MEX_CMD mex PATHS /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin)
  ```
- set CMake variable *CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH*:

  ```
  list(APPEND CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin")
  ```
- set CMake variable *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* (without `/bin` suffix):

  ```
  list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a")
  ```

**Without modification** of `CMakeLists.txt`:

- Set *PATH* environment variable (from the shell, before executing `cmake`):

  ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin
  ```
- Pass CMake variable *CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH* to the `cmake`:

  ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin <...>
  ```
- Pass CMake variable *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* (without `/bin` suffix) to the `cmake`:

  ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a <...>
  ```

Comment: thx a lot! {cmake -DCMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin <...>} worked like a charm